# Can't route after user login in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

After implementing my latest addition to my rails app (authentication using bcrypt), I realized my rails app can no longer route to any of the links in the `static_pages` controller. Is there a way around this? Is it a problem with my route implementation?

**Before**: localhost:3000/home

**After Login:** localhost:3000/users/2

**Error that I get when I click on home or any other link after login:**

> GET localhost:3000/users/home 404 (Not Found)

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
      resources :user
      root  'static_pages#home'
      match '/alex' , to: 'static_pages#alex', via: 'get'
      match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
      match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
      match '/home', to:'static_pages#home', via: 'get'
      match '/contact', to:'static_pages#contact', via:'get'
      match 'users/show' , to: 'users#show', via: 'get'
      get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
      post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
      delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
      get '/signup' => 'users#new'
      resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
end
```

My Header File located in Layouts:

```
   <div id = "navbar">
  <ul id = "menu-nav">
   <li class = "nav-item"> <a href= "home"  >      <i class="fa fa-home">       </i>   Home </a> </li>
   <li class = "nav-item"> <a href= "help"> <i class="fa fa-music"></i>    Music </a> </li>
   <li class = "nav-item"> <a href= "about" >  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>   Artist Discovery </a> </li>
  <li class = "nav-item"> <a href= "#"> <i class="fa fa-paper-plane">    </i>  News </a> </li>
   <li class = "nav-item"> <a href= "#"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>  Alex!        </a> </li>
    <% if @users == nil %>
    <li class = "nav-item"> <a href= "signup"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Sign Up </a> </li>
     <li class = "nav-item"> <a href= "login"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Login </a> </li>
     <% end %>
      </ul>
     </div>
```

Rake Routes:

```
  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
       root GET    /                         static_pages#home
       alex GET    /alex(.:format)           static_pages#alex
       help GET    /help(.:format)           static_pages#help
       about GET    /about(.:format)          static_pages#about
       home GET    /home(.:format)           static_pages#home
        contact GET    /contact(.:format)        static_pages#contact
       users_show GET    /users/show(.:format)     users#show
       login GET    /login(.:format)          sessions#new
          POST   /login(.:format)          sessions#create
     logout DELETE /logout(.:format)         sessions#destroy
     signup GET    /signup(.:format)         users#new
      users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
             POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
       new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
       edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
            PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
           sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)       sessions#create
      new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   sessions#new
      session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   sessions#destroy
```

Comment: Can you copy the logs and paste here.

Comment: The problem is probably in your links. Please post the code where your links are implemented.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/users/Program.m4a Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: do you have any before actions that rewrite the url? are you using the url_ helpers?  show the code that is generating your links

Comment: Please run `rake routes` from the terminal and add the result to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your 'home' link with this:

```
<%= link_to "Home", home_url %>
```

Comment: The link_to is a rails helper to create links. `home_url` references the 'home' Prefix you see in your rake routes. I strongly recommend that you read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: More info about the link_to helper: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 0):

Use slashes for before url on **a** tag

```
<a href='/home' > Home </a>
```

or use Rails option, all these should work...

```
<%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
<%= link_to 'Home', home_path %>
<%= link_to 'Home', home_url %>
```

One more thing.

If you are using newer version of Rails < 4, then suggesting to use **get** instead of match.

```
get "home" => 'static_page#home'
```